# Auto Sensing in Modern Switching Equipment

Tags: switch, switching, duplex, automation, half-duplex

Ive noticed that Modern switching equipment will auto sense whether it should be DTE or DCE. It will also auto sense whether the line can be in full duplex mode, or if it must be in half duplex. Ive been thing about stuff and I was wondering how does this auto sensing happen? What is the scheme or technology that it is using?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (autonegotiation) is explained in various sections of the IEEE 802.3 specifications.

Auto-MDIX is mostly a function of gigabit interfaces being able to TX and RX on all four pairs. I don't recall this being part of 802.3, but the logic for it (looking for carrier signal, and/or link pulses) is simple enough that anything capable of gig will support it.